# How to add Slider Value to Thumb Image?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a `UISlider` which I would like to customise. I would like to add the `UISlider` value which is a `Float` (I am converting to `Int`) to the actual thumb image.

How would you go about doing this? I know how to grab the `UISlider` value but I do not know how to set it to the thumb.

So as I slide, I want the thumb section to update with the current value.

The scale is from 1-10

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some image of exactly how you want it to appear?

Comment: I can't add image yet since my rank is low. As you "slide" I want the circle on the slide which is there by default to display the number it is currently on. So if it was 1-10 I want it to display those numbers. Thanks

Comment: @prabodhprakash No it is not the same. Please remove your comment! Thanks

Comment: @prabodhprakash Click the link for an image!

Comment: Why cannot the possible duplicate link, solve it?